# How to learn a new library/framework in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I would like to delve into the Yesod web framework but I am not really sure how to do it. It would be perfect if I could test each method individually and interactively in GHCi. So I really want to know how it works internally. It is not just about how to use Yesod or any other library. Is this a reasonable way to do it? How deal others with learning a new library in Haskell?

Answer (score 3):

Yesod heavily relies on Template Haskell, quasiquotes and compilation, even for templates.  You could test it to some extent on the command line, but this is going to be very inconvenient.  However, the [Yesod Book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book) is very comprehensive and gives a beginner-friendly introduction.

Answer (score 3):

Web frameworks aren't exactly the easiest thing to test on a method by method basis because they need a lot of context.  Since they are primarily dealing with network communication they invariably have to run in some monad (IO at the very least).  The three most popular Haskell web frameworks today all define their own monad to make things more convenient.  Typically this will include a good bit of state under the covers to keep track of things like headers, parsed query string and post parameters, etc.  This means that if you want to test at least some of the web server API you'll have to have a complete HTTP request and/or the underlying data needed derived from the request by the web server monad.

Now it's certainly possible to create an API that makes all of the above easier to do.  Yesod's version of this is in the wai-test package.  Snap's version is in the Snap.Test module in snap-core.

Yesod also relies a lot on Template Haskell (TH), which is Haskell's meta-programming library (like Lisp macros).  All three web frameworks use TH in places, but Yesod uses it more heavily with its custom quasiquoted DSLs.  TH requires two passes.  First you have to compile the TH code, then that code is executed, generating new code.  Then the new code gets compiled into your program along with everything else.  This two-pass system means that in general code requiring TH will be harder to play with by hand in GHCi than code without it.

Typically in my web applications I don't just run GHCi from scratch.  I usually am loading another code file that I've written.  That allows us to work around the Template Haskell problem because the Template Haskell parts are specified in the file and the code gets generated when I start up GHCi.  From then on out you can play with whatever functions were generated.

Answer (score 1):

Playing in ghci is a good way to learn a library, but for a framework like yesod, you need to get yourself familiar with the structure first.

I suggest you to follow the [tutorial](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Yesod-tutorial-for-newbies/) first. After you are familiar with the basic code structure, you can focus on the related libraries specifically, e.g. routes, templates, persistent. And when learning these libraries, ghci would be your friend.